# Is it realistic to use house ads in a magazine mockup?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've been learning InDesign, got all the basics now, but now Ive moved onto learning about how to put adverts together. (http://www.slideshare.net/AleaseMichelle/creating-an-magazine-ad-with-adobe-indesign is what I used on how to create adverts).

My question is on InDesign and putting together adverts; how many magazines still use in-house advertisements (I've created two fictional magazines -  a news magazine A4 size, like Time magazine (mainly a magazine - I used an InDesign tutorial on InDesign basics for this) and a car magazine, like [this one](http://content.yudu.com/Library/A2el4x/AutoExchangeWales060/resources/index.htm?referrerUrl=http%3A%2F%2Ffree.yudu.com%2Fitem%2Fdetails%2F1241317%2FAuto-Exchange-Wales-060913) is.
I did look up on Google, but am not sure about some things ..

With regard to the second link, do you think that was in-house ads or templates, or probably just PDF files?

This is not for a project, it's solely for learning purposes, there is no individual requesting the adverts.

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. I edited your title to reflect the question content and make it more applicable to our site.

Answer (score 1):

oh my gods yes. There are always holes to fill, bits which fall between the cracks (one-eights or one-sixteenths or a weird L-shaped space), advertisers who pull out at the last second, specialized publications to promote (college guide, best-of-locale issue, wedding book), and actual services which need to be advertised (subscription rollovers, upcoming special issues, classified sections).

Magazines and newspapers categorically run house ads.